# Can use special characters in one place but not other ɷ, Ø, ×

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Language: Python
I'm trying to export data where the end-users have used a lot of special characters. For this, I had to use characters that does not appear on the keyboard to avoid any mix-up.

I'm using Pandas to export the data. This works fine. However, when it tries to write the CSV with the special characters ɷ, Ø, × as delimiter, quote characters and escape characters, the script throws the below error:

`TypeError: "delimiter" must be string, not bytes`

Interesting part is that the same script being executed in another machine WITH SAME DOCKER IMAGE works just fine. It also work fine on my local.

Checked the Python and the package versions. They tally.
Checked if the same docker image is being used.

Comment: Could be something to do with the character encoding. https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-what-is-encoding

Comment: Show the code you are having trouble with, input, and desired output.  Make a [mcve] that produces the error claimed.  There should be no reason not to use the standard delimiter(,) and quote(") characters.